# Can't get code to work using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
    $query = '  Declare @MemCode Varchar(12);
                Declare @ConCounter decimal(28,0);
                Set @MemCode = null;
                Set @ConCounter = null; 

                EXECUTE spQMInsEventMember_TMS 
                "'.$masterEventCode.'",
                "'.$eventCode.'",
                '.$memberContactTitle.',
                "'.$guestFirstName.'",
                "'.$guestLastName.'",
                '.$address.',
                '.$townDescription.',
                '.$countryCode.',
                '.$postZip.',
                '.$STD.',
                '.$phone.',
                "'.$guestEmail.'",
                '.$isMember.',
                '.$divisionCode.',
                '.$statusCode.',
                '.$subStatusCode.',
                '.$memberTypeCode.',
                '.$memberTitles.',
                '.$memberSubType.',
                '.$classCode.',
                '.$subClassCode.',@MemCode OUTPUT,@ConCounter OUTPUT;
                SELECT @MemCode AS member_code, @ConCounter AS contact_counter;';
    //print_r($query);

    $res = $this->dbh->query($query);
print_r $res;
```

OUTPUT:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["RESULT"]=> string(2) "OK" ["CONTACTCOUNTER"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(522) " Declare @MemCode Varchar(12); Declare @ConCounter decimal(28,0); Set @MemCode = null; Set @ConCounter = null; EXECUTE spQMInsEventMember_TMS "AC", "LAC1112", NULL, "Fred", "Smith", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "b@b.com", 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,@MemCode OUTPUT,@ConCounter OUTPUT; SELECT @MemCode AS member_code, @ConCounter AS contact_counter;" } }
```

Comment: If I take the output and Copy and paste it into SQLServer Management Tools, it works fine.

All I'm trying to do is Call a Stored Procedure and get the Result Set.

Running in SQLServer as I said, returns the correct results of member_code and contact_counter.

Answer (score 0):

Query returns a PDOStatement object, not the results array.

To get all the results at once, try:

```
$sth = $this->dbh->query($query);

if(!$sth)
{
    // Query failed. Find out Why
    $error = sth->errorInfo();
    print_r $error;
}
else
{
    // We got results.
    $res = sth->fetchAll();
    print_r $res;
}
```

Comment: That returns an empty result set.

Comment: Just had a look at the PDO Libraries that are installed.
(I have no control over these).

I believe it is using pdo_dblib.

There is also pdo_sqlite installed.

Is there are better way to connect to SQLServer?

Comment: Show me the code that you currently use to connect your PDO? Also, what are the results of `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`?

Comment: Interestingly, 

print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); 

Results in:

Array ( [0] => dblib [1] => mysql [2] => sqlite )

Comment: The code used to connect is using:

$localdbh = new PDO('dblib:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);
   $this->dbh = $localdbh;
   return $localdbh;

Comment: Other code is working fine (i.e. all other stored procs that don't have output parameters)